# onCreate() method is not working properly in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-activity, android-6.0-marshmallow, oncreate, start-activity

**[CLOSED]**

I have a two activity called A and B.

ActivityA (Launcher) shows list data (RecyclerView) and data is downloaded from the WebService.

ActivityB shows list item detail when i press list item.

The problem is:

When i press back button from ActivityB, ActivityA's onCreate() method working and re-downloading already downloaded datas like relaunching app. I don't want to re-download or re-call onCreate() method.

I tested two device has pre Marshmallow OS:

- Samsung Galaxy S5 (OS version 4.4.4)
- Sony Xperia (OS version 4.1.2)

and the result is:

When i press back button from ActivityB, ActivityA is not re-downloading. ActivityA already shows lastly positioned list. I want this in Marshmallow.

My Marshmallow device is Nexus 5 (OS version 6.0.1)

How can i solve this problem?

[SOME CODE BELOW]

```
// This is ActivityA
public class MainView extends AppCompatActivity {

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_view);

    ...

    if (NetworkChecker.isNetAvailable(context)) {
        mDataSet = update(); // this method calling WebService
    } else {
        mDataSet = Database.getDatas(); // this method reading datas from sqlite.
    }
    createListView(mDataSet);

    ...
}

private void createListView(List<NamecardEntity> mDataSet) {
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.itemsRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration =
            new DividerItemDecorator(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mDataSet);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
}

...
}

public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerSwipeAdapter<ListAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {

...

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    Entity item = mDataset.get(position);

    ...

    viewHolder.front.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, DetailView.class));
        }
    });

    ...
}

}

// This is ActivityB
public class DetailView extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail_view);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    ...
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_filter, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_filter:
            // TODO filter
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}
}

// In Manifest.xml
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity
    android:name=".MainView"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".DetailView"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
</application>
```

**[EDITED] I FOUND REASEN**

I put some Log into ActivityA Lifecycle, and the result is:

**When i run the application on the Xperia. (pre Marshmallow test result):**

ActivityA state log is:

- onCreate
- onStart
- onResume

then select list item and starting ActivityB

ActivityA state log is:

- onPause
- onStop

then i press back button from ActivityB and navigate back to A

ActivityA state log is:

- onRestart
- onStart
- onResume

**When i run the application on the Nexus 5. (Marshmallow test result):**

ActivityA state log is:

- onCreate
- onStart
- onResume

then select list item and starting ActivityB

ActivityA state log is:

- onPause
- onStop
- onDestroy  <- **this is the reason, why this method called in Marshmallow**

then i press back button from ActivityB and navigate back to A

ActivityA state log is:

- onCreate  <- **onCreate() called, cause onDestory() called already, this is the problem**
- onStart
- onResume

**ACTIVITY LIFECYCLE IS WORKS DIFFERENT IN MARSHMALLOW, WHY? THAT IS THE WHY I GETTING PROBLEM. PLS HELP**

Comment: Is Activity A declared with any special `launchMode` or other attributes, such as `noHistory`?

Comment: @Raghavendra: ok will post some code ASAP

Comment: @Raghavendra: code posted.

Comment: @qbix: Manifest.xml posted.

Comment: It is not believable that `Marshmallow` device always kills Activity A without having special permission. Can you please check the Developer Settings on that device and see if `Don't Keep Activities` option is checked or not.
--- Other thing that could be possible reason for this is Doze mode check this link to disable it "https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-disable-doze-android-marshmallow", although it gets active only when device is idle or something.. but give it a try as well ;)

Comment: @AnkitBansal: i checked Developer Options, Don't Keep Activities enabled. you save my life. Thank you. I hate the man WHO ENABLED THIS option :)

Comment: Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Android Marshmallow is working fine. You have this problem because you didn't correctly adhere to the activity lifecycle.

[image]

Note that it is up to Android to destroy the `Activity` or not. You have to take account on that. Turns out in your case on previous Android versions your `Activity` was destroyed, so when you navigated back it passed through onCreate(). Now it does not destroy it, so it doesn't go through `onCreate()`.

The correct way to refresh data is to **always** do it on the `onResume()` method to make sure it will be called no matter if Android destroys the `Activity` or not.

Comment: @TsomoNe Your edit is exactly what I already told you. I also told you why the cycle is "different" on Marshmallow (in fact, it is NOT different) and how to fix it. Did you try the solution I'm proposed?